# docker container rabbitmqctl shutdown stuck "Waiting for PID xxx to terminate"

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

Trying to install and configure rabbitmq inside a docker container. Same steps work just fine on the host. But inside a docker container, "rabbitmqctl shutdown" just hangs there with the messsage. I have been stuck with this for a few weeks. Badly need this resolved so I can move forward. I will send a amazon gift card for anyone who can help solve the problem!!!!

```
Shutting down RabbitMQ node rabbit@dev_moog running at PID 13039
Waiting for PID 13039 to terminate
```

ps -ef shows a process called "[beam] ", I have tried killing that. It won't die.

```
ps -ef |egrep "13039|rabbitmqctl" |grep -v grep
moogsoft 13039     1  0 19:15 ?        00:00:03 [beam] <defunct>
moogsoft 15137 12765  0 19:15 pts/0    00:00:00 /home/moogsoft//cots/erlang/lib/erlang/erts-8.3/bin/beam.smp -B -- -root /home/moogsoft//cots/erlang/lib/erlang -progname erl -- -home /home/moogsoft -- -boot start_clean -noshell -noinput -noshell -hidden -smp enable -kernel inet_dist_listen_min 35672 -kernel inet_dist_listen_max 35682 -sasl errlog_type error -mnesia dir "/home/moogsoft/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@dev_moog" -run escript start -escript main rabbitmqctl_escript -extra /home/moogsoft/cots/rabbitmq-server/escript/rabbitmqctl shutdown
```

Comment: You don't need to run commands like that inside a container (you shouldn't usually need a shell inside a container at all).  Just `docker stop` and `docker rm` the container.

Comment: This is part of the docker image build process. I am trying to create a image with rabbitmq inisde the image. So it's part of the installation for the app that is going to use.

Comment: You'd usually run RabbitMQ and other (long-running, stateful) support processes in separate containers.  Use a tool like Docker Compose to run a [`rabbitmq`](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq) container alongside your application container.  Don't try to package or run multiple things in a single container.